# Как сделать так, чтобы картинка в Slick-slider не обрезалась при уменьшении размера экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Как в slick-slider сделать так, чтобы картинка не обрезалась при ЛЮБЫХ разрешениях экрана? Я имею ввиду, что ту картинку которую вы видите на десктопной версии, было так же видно и при маленьких разрешениях экрана без обрезаний?
Я пробовал object-fit, как отдельно так и в связке с различными свойствами. Так же пробовал такой способ, что блоку .item, в котором хранится фотография задаются такие свойства:

```css
overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
```

А самой картинке такие:

```css
 position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Но в итоге это не помогло

Сам сайт http://ilyin1ib.beget.tech/

Весь код jsfiddle.net/juc0q4hx/

Как в итоге сделать, чтобы выглядело вот так и чтобы ничего не плыло и не урезалось?

Как надо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я же писал уже - удали slick-theme.css и так же slick.css , вот пример только с jquery + slick.js: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyWMMEj - медиазапросы писал от балды но проверял на мобиле

Comment: мне он дальше на этом сайте понадобится, поэтому отпадает

Comment: Что отпадает? я не понял

Comment: удаление css, к тому же я уже справился с проблемой

Comment: То что Вы important  наделали это не справился